# Sequelize v4 | Instance Methods not working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I've been trying to update my code to accommodate the newest upgrades to Sequelize. I'm using

- Sequelize: 4.2.0
- Node: 7.10.0
- NPM: 5.0.3

**The Problem**

I can't seem to set the User model properly. I've implemented some instance methods that don't seem to be working. The class must not be instantiated properly.

**user.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    attributes ....
  }, { 
    hooks: { 
      afterCreate(user, options) {
        user.testFunction();
      }
    }
  });

  // Instance methods
  User.prototype.testFunction = () => {
    this.firstName = "John";
  }

  // Class methods
  User.anotherTestFunction = () => {
    User.findOne().then(() => doSomething());
  }

  return User;
}
```

**index.js**

```
var sequelize;
sequelize = new Sequelize(config.DATABASE_URL);

db.User = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/user.js');

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

**usersController.js**

```
var db = require('../path/to/db');

function create_post_function = (req, res) => {
  var body = getBody();
  db.User.create(body).then(user => respondSuccess());
}
```

Now, everything in this example works perfectly EXCEPT the instance method!!!

I'm continually getting `TypeError: Cannot set property 'firstName' of undefined`

For some reason, it's not applying the instance method to the sequelize Model. Very strange, but I'm probably doing something noticeably wrong and not seeing it.

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can't use arrow functions since they can't access `this` in the appropriate context (it will reference the parent scope). Try writing them like this -

```
// Instance methods
User.prototype.testFunction = function testFunction() {
  this.firstName = "John";
}

// Class methods
User.anotherTestFunction = function anotherTestFunction() {
  User.findOne().then(() => doSomething());
}
```

Comment: You just saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: I've never felt so lucky to find an answer. I had no idea you couldn't use `this` with arrow functions. I would have wasted so much time looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: Actually you can use 'this' in the arrow functions, but context will be set from parent env.